# Tried in different ways but sidebar not working?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, actions

```
function Y_widget_register(){
 register_sidebar(array(
     'name'=>esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'Y-07' ),
     'id'=> 'y-sidebar',
     'description'=>'Dynamic Right Sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="y-widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
     'before_title'  => '<h2 class="y-widget-title">',
     'after_title'   => '</h2>'


  ) );
}


add_action('widgets-init','Y_widget_register' );
```

I tried different styles previous versions too but not working, what possibilities making my code not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'Y_widget_register' );
```

You have a typo - use underscores.

Here is the working piece:

```
function Y_widget_register() {
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => esc_html__('Sidebar', 'Y-07'),
    'id' => 'y-sidebar',
    'description' => 'Dynamic Right Sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="y-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</section>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="y-widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>'
));
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'Y_widget_register');
```